# stream_select(), signals and Stdin in PHP

Tags: php, select, stream, stdin

I am trying to write a native PHP CLI application which reads data (log data) from stdin and does some handling after.

I got a first working version with a simple while-Loop:

```
while ($line = fgets(STDIN)) {
    // Do my stuff here
}
```

When installing signal handling via

```
function signal_handler(int $signo, mixed $siginfo) {
    // ...
}

pcntl_async_signals(TRUE);
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP, 'signal_handler');
```

this works partly: The signals are only processed after each `fgets()`.

I tried to use `stream_select()` with NULL as timeout and some other stuff, but this lead to a massive system load :-)

Is there any best practice to use `stream_select()` and `fgets()` on stdin to read data until it's "ready" and wait/pause indefinitely else but let signals being processed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stream_set_blocking(STDIN, 0);` to remove the blocking.

Example:

```
function signal_handler(int $signo,  $siginfo) {
    exit("signal caught\n");
}

stream_set_blocking(STDIN, 0);
pcntl_async_signals(TRUE);
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP, 'signal_handler');

echo "pid=" . posix_getpid() . "\n";

echo "Listening input...\n";
while (true) {
    while ($line = fgets(STDIN)) {
        echo "Input: '$line'\n";
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
Pid=46834
Listening input...
Input: 'test'
signal caught
```

See [`stream_set_blocking()`](https://php.net/stream_set_blocking)